# Why Does Ignite Use Spring framework?

Tags: ignite

I had used Spring framework in my apps and while it is nice conceptually, it is not suitable for real-time apps due to its run-time overhead. For instance, http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Failed-to-map-keys-for-cache-all-partition-nodes-left-the-grid-td23510.html shows the actual run-time Spring stack.

The Spring features that Ignite uses for loading application-defined beans are just many layers wrapped around simple Java reflection features. So Why Ignite uses Spring instead of straight Java'reflection ?

To make Ignite more performant, is there plan with Ignite to switch from Spring framework to Java reflection features ?

Similarly, if Ignite uses Spring Boot to handle port requests, why does it not use a light-weight framework such as www.sparkjava.com ?

Answer (score 5):

Ignite uses Spring only to convert XML configuration files into configuration beans during startup. This way Ignite provides a convenient well-known way of configuring instead of introducing a custom one. In the runtime, after node is started, Spring is not used for anything.

In the thread you provided it's actually other way around - Spring invokes Ignite. Apparently, that's a Spring application with an embedded Ignite node.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin for the answer. Since Ignite only uses Spring to load the configuration beans, in order for it not to go through Spring to use those beans in run-time after the node is started, does Ignite then use Java's built-in reflection to use them ?